# Bounded function and uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have $A \subseteq \mathbb R^p$. Let $f_n : A \rightarrow \mathbb R^q$ be a bounded function and

$$\lVert f_n\rVert_A = \text{sup}\;\{\lVert f_n(x) \rVert : x \in A\}$$

for $n \in \mathbb N$.

If we have

$$\lVert f_{n+2} - f_{n+1}\rVert_A \leq \epsilon\lVert f_{n+1} - f_{n}\rVert_A$$

for some $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, prove that there exists a function a $f : A \rightarrow \mathbb R^q$ such that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $A$.

Roughly, I can see why  $(f_n)$ would converge uniformly. The difference between $f_{n+1}$ and $f_{n}$ gets smaller due to $\epsilon$ as $n\to\infty$.

However, I am struggling with how I should go about proving this rigorously.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that you can chain the inequalities down to $\|f_2-f_1\|\epsilon^n$,  which gets you a geometric sequence,  the floor you need for uniform continuity will just be the $n$ you start at in that formula.

Answer (score 1):

It is straightforward to show that for any $n \ge 1$,

$$\lVert f_{n+1} - f_n \rVert_A \leq \epsilon^{n-1} \lVert f_2 - f_1 \rVert_A. $$

Given some $\delta > 0$, choose $N$ such that $(\epsilon^{N-1} / 1 - \epsilon) \lVert f_2 - f_1 \rVert_A < \delta$. Then, for any $m,n > N$ with $m>n$,

$$
\begin{align*}
\lVert f_{m} - f_n \rVert_A &\leq \sum_{i=n}^{m-1} \lVert f_{i+1} - f_i\rVert_A \\
&\leq \sum_{i=n}^{m-1} \epsilon^{i-1} \lVert f_2 - f_1\rVert_A \\
&\leq \sum_{i=n}^{\infty} \epsilon^{i-1} \lVert f_2 - f_1\rVert_A < \delta.
\end{align*}
$$

It follows that the sequence $(f_n)$ is Cauchy. Since $\mathbb{R}^q$ is complete, it converges uniformly to some $f$.